# Schedule Cron to skip first Saturday of every month

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I need a `cron` to skip the first Saturday of every month. I know we can run on specific days using the below command, but is there a way to skip on a particular day for every month?

//To run on first Monday of every month

```
 0 2 * * 1 [ date '+\%m' == date '+\%m' -d "1 week ago" ] || /path/to/command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there seem to be no option in Cron. 
I'm going with script for the above need.

```
**if [ $(date +%d) -le 7 ] && [ $(date +%u) -eq 1 ] ;**
```

`[ $(date +%d) -le 7 ]` - Checks if the days fall in first 7 days of month

`[ $(date +%u) -eq 6 ]` - Checks if day is equal to Saturday

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is your command a binary file or just script?
How about the idea to add something like that in the beginning:

```
[ $(date | awk '{print $1}') == "Sat" ] && exit 1 || { \
# your code here
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works in cron (don't forget to escape the %):

```
0 2 * * * [[ `date '+\%u'` -ne '6' && `date '+\%d'` -lt '8' ]] || [[ `date '+\%d'` -gt '7' ]] && /path/to/command
```

The logic is :

- If the day is not a Saturday and the day of the month is 1-7, execute the command
- If the above is not correct, check if the day of the month is bigger than 7, if so execute

Another way would be to invert the logic :

```
0 2 * * * [[ ! ( `date '+\%u'` -eq '6' && `date '+\%d'` -lt '8' ) ]] && /path/to/command
```

The logic is :

- If the day is not the first Saturday, execute the command

> **`man 5 crontab`**
>
> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or
>   a "%" character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.  A "%" character in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (\), will be changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as standard input.

Comment: 22 07 * * * [ `date '+%u'` -ne '2' && `date '+%d'` -lt 17 ] || [ `date '+%d'` -gt 17 ] && /<path>/script.sh.
The above command is edited to trigger the script and test right now. But it is not working. Am I doing anything wrong?.
It has to run the script if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Throwing the below error.
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

Comment: you need to escape the % (and for some reason i needed the double [[ ]] :
`[[ \`date '+\%u'\` -ne '2' && \`date '+\%d'\` -lt 17 ]] || [[ \`date '+\%d'\` -gt 17 ]]  && echo foo > ~/foo.txt 2> ~/foo.err`

Comment: Yes this works.
Just a small correction in your logic line 2, its 8+ not 8- :)

Comment: Hi, I'm tryin to do the same, my job should run on all the Fridays except for the first Friday of a month. 

``0 17 * * 5 [[ ! ( `date '+\%u'` -eq '5' && `date '+\%d'` -lt '8' ) ]] && /usr/bin/python3 
test.py``

This doesn't work for me, not able to fig out what i'm doing wrong, can you help?

By 'escape the %', are you asking to remove the % ?